# finding the logic error in a greetUser function

Tags: javascript

My professor says I have a logic error in the greetUser function of code I was already graded on. The code is based on the example in the text, so I'm stunned as to determining the logic. This was her message to me:

> The `greetUser` function is not reading the cookie correctly for the returning visitor.
>    Check this line of code in the `readCookie` function - it has a logic error.

This is the `readCookie` function:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var x = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = cookies[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the `greetUser` function:

```
function greetUser(){
    userName = readCookie("rock_username");
    if(userName)
        alert("Hello " + userName + ", I missed you.");
    else 
        alert("Hello, I am your pet rock");
}
```

From my novice eyes it all looks logical to me, the same as it was in the text example.
Any suggestions

Comment: It executes but not to my professor's expectations. Like she said it stops short of returning the visitor. I understand that part, but Just don't see the error in the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
var c = cookies[i];
```

You are iterating on "ca" (what is that?) instead of "x", and then you are reading from the `cookies` array? 3 different variables, same meaning?

I'll explain: `var x = document.cookie.split(';');` splits the string stored in `document.cookie` into an array, that will effectively be held inside the `x` parameter.

Then, inside the `for()` construct, you are increasing `i` up until the amount of elements found inside the array you just created from splitting the string. That way, each time you do `c = x[i]`; (correct version) you will get the next portion of the `document.cookie` string that you split with the ';' character.

This allows you to work on all the interesting parts of `document.cookie`, which are, by definition, the user agent (browser) cookies. In your example, you are iterating over the cookies to find a specific one - the 'name' cookie - in order to print it as a greet to the user.

Good luck!

Comment: So you're saying the ca is an iteration? I'm learning something here. I was basically copying code not knowing the meaning behind it. I haven't gotten to arrays yet. I'll try putting x where ca was - trial and error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @swydell oh, then you have a long (and interesting - wish I could re-discover it) way to go :) I'm adding an explanation to the answer so you can understand it better, check in less than a minute!

Comment: I like your explanation. It starts to make sense, kind of. But I don't expect to comprehend it all at once, just piece meal.